# Eclipse not Starting

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno, ubuntu-11.10

I was using Ubuntu 11.04 & my Eclipse was working fine . I was using Eclipse Juno but now i have upgraded my ubuntu from 11.04 to 11.10 but my Eclipse is not even starting now .

Comment: Maybe some error messages or log could help?

Comment: Nopx .. Its shown a block window with no error. Many times i have started my PC & tried to run but fails.

Comment: When i run an icon with "?" sign appears in Launcher & it stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859823), try moving your existing `eclipse.ini`, and let Eclipse recreate it.
See if that allows Eclipse to start.

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini.bup
```

If not, then a copy of the error message or of the eclipse logs (`workspaceLocation/.metadata/.log`) will help.

---

Regarding the launcher with an improper icon ('`?`'), you can also follow [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1748360)

> Leave the "Type" as "Application" and click "Browse" next to "Command". Navigate to your Eclipse installation and binary e.g. /opt/eclipse/eclipse.
>
> Now click the springy icon and change the icon to the `eclipse.xpm` file in the same folder as your binary.
>
> Click OK then move the icon somewhere out of the way e.g. `~/.local/applications`.
>
> Once you have done that, just drag that icon over to your launcher.